# Why can't array initialization refer to a constant member variable in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have a data structure which is a data provider and is setup with an array of values and one particular value I want to set is an value from an instance member.

To frame it as a concrete example, I get an error when I do

```
struct DataProvider {
    let largeInt = 50000
    let ints: [Int] = [2, 3, 4, largeInt]
}
```

The compiler says

> Instance member 'largeInt' cannot be used on data type 'DataProvider'

Is there a way I can introduce largeInt as part of the initialisation of ints other than actually by replacing it with the literal value 50000?

Comment: Try specifing the type: `let largeInt: Int = 50000`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is already explained by vacawama. And you can also use static

```
struct DataProvider {
    static let largeInt = 50000
    let ints: [Int] = [2, 3, 4, largeInt]
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, that works as well.  Upvoted.  In this case `largeInt` is accessed like `DataProvider.largeInt` from outside of the structure.  In the OP's original example, `largeInt` was an instance variable which would be accessed from an instance, for example `DataProvider().largeInt`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the way you defined it is that `largeInt` isn't available for reading until the structure is done initializing, so you can't use it in the initialization of another property.

Instead of initializing it inline, you can initialize it with an initializer:

```
struct DataProvider {
    let largeInt: Int
    let ints: [Int]
    init() {
        largeInt = 50000
        ints = [2, 3, 4, largeInt]
    }
}
```

Or you can pass `largeInt` into the initializer:

```
struct DataProvider {
    let largeInt: Int
    let ints: [Int]

    init(largeInt: Int) {
        self.largeInt = largeInt
        ints = [2, 3, 4, largeInt]
    }
}

let dp = DataProvider(largeInt: 50000)
```